# mysql COUNT with UNION php

Tags: php, mysql

i am having a problem adding COUNT to my query.
the query works fine but as soon as i add **COUNT(*) AS totalNum** 
i get 1 result from each table

```
$query = "(SELECT 'table1' AS tablename, navid, thumb, title, longText, clicks AS allClicks, COUNT(*) AS totalNum
FROM table1 
WHERE $column=1 
AND enabled=1)

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT 'table2' AS tablename, navid, thumb, title, longText, clicks AS allClicks, COUNT(*) AS totalNum 
FROM table2
WHERE $column=1 
AND enabled=1) 
ORDER BY allClicks DESC";


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $navid = $row['navid'];
    $thumb = $row['thumb'];
    $tablename = $row['tablename'];
    $title = strtoupper($row['title']);

    etc...

}
```

question: what is the best way to add **count(*)** into my my join query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an aggregate function, such as `COUNT`, you need to include a [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause:

```
(SELECT 
    'table1' AS tablename, 
    navid, 
    thumb, 
    title, 
    longText, 
    clicks AS allClicks, 
    COUNT(*) AS totalNum
FROM table1 
WHERE 
    $column=1 
    AND enabled=1
GROUP BY navid, thumb, title, longText, clicks)

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT 
    'table2' AS tablename, 
    navid, 
    thumb, 
    title, 
    longText, 
    clicks AS allClicks, 
    COUNT(*) AS totalNum 
FROM table2
WHERE 
    $column=1 
    AND enabled=1
GROUP BY navid, thumb, title, longText, clicks)
```

Comment: if i wanted to get the COUNT, would this do it in the while loop? $totalNum = $row['totalNum'];

Comment: I've never written a single line of PHP... but yea, that looks like it should work.

Comment: i keep getting a count result of 1

Comment: `COUNT` tells you how many rows in your result have the same values for `navid, thumb, title, longText, clicks`.  What are you wanting to get a count of?  The total number of rows in your result?